# Images doesnt load on website (on iPad)

Tags: html, ios, css, ipod

Im creating website with paralax effect. Today I heard that images just are not displayed on iPod ?!

I cant check that, because I dont have access to iPod. Can someone tell my why main pictures dont appear in iPod?

Website: http://www.badzlepszy.pl/Nebiolo2/

Answer (score 1):

The images you are using are multiple images of `2000x1200px` in size. There is a limit for the maximum amount of pixels allowed in an image. You can visit [this website](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/) to see which devices should be capable of displaying your images.

The iOS resource limits are described on the [Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) at the heading "Know iOS Resource Limits".

Using these large images on a iPod could cause the problem of not displaying the image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my ipod an can confirm that it looks odd. some of the images are shown though.

You have some errors in your html. Try to fix them first e.g.

```
<div id="sitelanguage"> outside of body tag
<div class="pasek_suwakow" style="top: 345px;> <-- " missing after 345px
</br></br>
```

see http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.badzlepszy.pl%2FNebiolo2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0